# How do I chmod a file and have it persist across multiple machines when I transfer it?

Tags: bash, terminal, permissions, chmod

There's a .sh script that I want to let an entire team be able to use on their own machines. Then I noticed that I needed to `chmod +x thescript.sh` on the file every time the script is newly downloaded into the machine.

Is there a way so that the +x permission is persistent even when uploading it so I don't need to keep chmod'ing?

EDIT: To clarify, the +x permission doesn't get carried over when I attach it to an email and it's then downloaded to a different machine. I haven't tried uploading it in general, but I'm assuming it would have the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In security terms, persisting +x would allow viruses to do their thing.

As an alternative, set the correct permissions on the file and then create a zip or tar archive. Unzipping will preserve the file permissions.

Comment: Good idea, just followed this advice instead. Now I understand one reason why some things that I download that are really only one file come in archives...

Comment: FYI: the default file creation permissions on Linux is controlled by `umask` https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: Can you provide more info on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -p flag to preserve file permissions:

```
cp -p src dest
```

or

```
rsync -p src dest
```

Comment: `scp -p src dest` too ;)